# PHP imagecreatefromstring() doesn't work when i enter a base64 decoded value

Tags: php, base64

So, I'm using the following code:

```
$currentIMG = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($img));
```

Where $img is a base64 string. When I echo base64_decode($img) it shows me a string (as it should), but when I use imagecreatefromstring() it shows the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object of class GdImage could not be
> converted to string

I can guarantee that the base64 string is not broken because it works on online base64 to image converters, so I can't figure out what's the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
function base64toImage($img) {
    $currentIMG = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($img));
    echo $currentIMG;       
}
```

Comment: But what is inside the string ? is it the raw binary string of what would normally be inside a png/jpeg ?

Comment: It seems that ether `$img` does not contain a string or the error is not coming from this line. Post the surrounding code.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/LLxZAgM.png this is decoded base64

Comment: Are you sure the line number mentioned in the error is for this `imagecreatefromstring` line ? Because it sounds like the conversion from string to *GD object* went fine, but later on you try to cast/coerce the object as a string (and that causes the error)

Comment: now I think that I have a configuration problem, because I created a new php file that I run with an imagefrompng() function having param. an PNG image from my pc and it is showing the same error

Comment: Uh... it's a png of a string of a image of a png?

Comment: That part isn't weird. The function basically expects a string like `file_get_contents('image.png')`

Comment: imagecreatefrompng('../desktop/c.png');  it's a PNG image

Comment: Oh I see, you screenshotted the dump. I thought that *was* the image you were encoding.

Comment: file_get_contents() works

Comment: I'm not sure what `imagecreatefrompng` has to do with this ? you shouldnt be needing both that and `imagecreatefromstring`.

Comment: i just wanted to verify if it's a configuration fault

Comment: the error appear when i use `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents('../desktop/c.png'))` too

Comment: We've both now told you that the error is probably coming from a line other than the one you've posted. Post the rest of the code.

Comment: I posted the code

Comment: yea theres your problem , on the next line. you cannot echo a GD object. Solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
echo $currentIMG;
```

Which tries to print a `GDImage` as if it is a string, use something like:

```
Header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($currentIMG);
```

Comment: It helped. But before when i was echo, it showed something like [image resurse #7]

Comment: Could be, i'm not sure if the GDImage has a `__toString` method, but either way you're not trying to print it. the object itself isnt in an imageformat, you need the `imagepng` or `imagejpeg` or one of their sisters to actually convert it into a usable format.